# I would like to have the donations in decending order.

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like for the vDonations to be in decending order I get this error when I try to run it

```
Unexpected element
xsl:sort
```

Code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>  
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>   
<xsl:param name="ppathPersons"   select="'file:///C:\Users\Randy\Documents\xml\projects\persons.xml'"/>   
<xsl:param name="ppathDonations"   select="'file:///C:\Users\Randy\Documents\XML\projects\money.xml'"/>   
<xsl:variable name="vPersons"    select="document($ppathPersons)"/>   
<xsl:variable name="vDonations"   select="document($ppathDonations)"/>   
<xsl:template match="/">   
<html>
<head>
<link href="money.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h2>The Lighthouse Donation List</h2>  
<p><img src="logo.jpg"/></p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Donor</th>
<th>Donation</th>
</tr>      
<xsl:apply-templates select="$vPersons/*/person"/>
</table>
</body>   
</html>  
</xsl:template>   
<xsl:template match="person">   
<tr>    
<td colspan="1">     
<xsl:value-of select="concat(firstName, ' ', lastName)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',street,' ' , city,' ', state, ' ', zip, ' ',  phone)"/>    
</td>    
<td colspan="1">     
<xsl:value-of select="$vDonations/*/*[@pin = current()/@pid]/@amount"/> 
<xsl:for-each select="$vDonations">
  <xsl:sort select="$ppathDonations" data-type="number" order="descending" case- order="upper-first"/>
</xsl:for-each>    
</td>   
</tr>  
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I've tried several different ways all of which have failed.

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you want sorted. Anyway, in my answer I give solution for two possible cases of the wanted processing.

Comment: The variable $vDonations holds a single node; there's no point sorting a singleton. xsl:sort needs to go inside an xsl:for-each or xsl:apply-templates that selects a sequence of nodes. But the message "Unexpected element xsl:sort" seems bizarre. I suspect that didn't come from the code above, but from some other incorrect attempt.

Comment: It did come from the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want the donations made by the same person displayed within one `td` in decreasing order, use**:

```
<xsl:template match="person">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(firstName, ' ', lastName)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',street,' ' , city,' ', state, ' ', zip, ' ',  phone)"/>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1">
            <xsl:for-each select="$vDonations/*/*[@pin = current()/@pid]">
                <xsl:sort select="@amount"
                data-type="number" order="descending"
                case-order="upper-first"/>

                <xsl:if test="position() >1">
                 <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="@amount"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**In case you want to display all donations in decreasing order, modify your transformation to this one**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="ppathDonations" select=
    "'file:///c:/temp/delete/donations.xml'"/>
    <xsl:param name="ppathPersons"   select=
     "'file:///c:/temp/delete/persons.xml'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vPersons"    select=
     "document($ppathPersons)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vDonations"   select=
     "document($ppathDonations)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <link href="money.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>The Lighthouse Donation List</h2>
                <p>
                    <img src="logo.jpg"/>
                </p>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Donor</th>
                        <th>Donation</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=
                       "$vDonations/*/donation">
                      <xsl:sort select="@amount" data-type="number"
                                order="descending"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="donation">
      <xsl:variable name="vPerson" select=
        "$vPersons/*/person[@pid = current()/@pin]"/>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <xsl:value-of select=
                 "concat($vPerson/firstName, ' ', $vPerson/lastName)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select=
                "concat(' ', $vPerson/street,' ' ,
                        $vPerson/city,' ',
                        $vPerson/state, ' ',
                        $vPerson/zip, ' ',
                        $vPerson/phone)"/>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1">
              <xsl:value-of select="@amount"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is executed with the two XML files you provided in your first question, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <link href="money.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>The Lighthouse Donation List</h2>
      <p><img src="logo.jpg"></p>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Donor</th>
            <th>Donation</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="1">David Olson 5133 Oak Street Delphi KY 89011 (532) 555-8981</td>
            <td colspan="1">10000</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="1">Jane Whitney 87 Hilltop Drive Jasper KY 89381 (534) 555-7493</td>
            <td colspan="1">10000</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="1">Lee Thomas 451 Unwin Court Jasper KY 89381 (534) 555-9082</td>
            <td colspan="1">100</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="1">Cindy Wu 31 Alice Avenue Delphi KY 89011 (532) 555-7212</td>
            <td colspan="1">50</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```